# what are the sequence of mutliple patches apply on magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, security, patches

Have a magento instance C.E 1.7.0.2.

Any patches did not applied on this instance and now want to apply patches.

As per as @benmarks sheet . require to apply patches below patches:

- SUPEE-6482
- SUPEE-6285,
- SUPEE-5994,
- SUPEE-5344,
- SUPEE-1533,
- APPSEC-212

  Started `to apply patch from bottom APPSEC-212` and it `applied successfully till SUPEE-5994`

Whenever try to apply SUPEE-6285 and it does not apply.

***Showing Checking .... checking.***

Now i want to know why this error showing

**Is require to change the sequence apply patches like:**

- SUPEE-6482
- SUPEE-5344,
- SUPEE-1533,
- APPSEC-212
- SUPEE-6285,
- SUPEE-5994,

  Am i right?

Comment: You have to apply the patches in the order they were released, oldest first. What exactly is the error message? `"Checking ..... checking"` does not look like the real patch output

Comment: will give u screen shot shorly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Magento 1.7.0.2 the order of applying patches should be:

1. APPSEC-212
2. SUPEE-1533
3. SUPEE-5344
4. SUPEE-5994
5. SUPEE-6285
6. SUPEE-6482