# Which patches do I need to apply on Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, security, patches

The site http://fabrizioballiano.net/magento-patches/ listes for Magento 1.7.0.2 the following patches:

- SUPEE-6482: SUPEE-6482 for CE 1.7.x - 1.8.0.0 (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-6285: SUPEE-6285 for CE 1.7.0.0 - 1.7.0.2 (0.05 MB)
- SUPEE-6237: USPS API Patch - CE 1.6.x-1.9.x (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-5994: SUPEE-5994 for CE 1.6.0.0 - 1.9.1.1 (0.04 MB)
- SUPEE-5344: Magento-CE-v1.7.x (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-1533: Magento-CE-v1.7.x (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-4291/4334: Magento-CE-v1.7.x-1.8.x (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-1868: Magento-CE-v1.7.x (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-2725: Magento-CE-v1.7.0.0-1.8.1.0 (0.01 MB)
- PHP 5.4: Magento-CE-v1.7.0.0-1.7.0.2 (0.01 MB)
- APPSEC-212: Magento-CE-v1.6.0.0-1.7.0.2 (0.01 MB)

This sounds a lot to me.

Is this a mistake on the site?

Which patches do I need for Magento CE 1.7.0.2 ?

**Edit:** 
My question is related by slightly different to [what are the sequence of mutliple patches apply on magento 1.7.0.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79320/what-are-the-sequence-of-mutliple-patches-apply-on-magento-1-7-0-2) which asks for the order of patches, but does not list all of those I found here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list is correct. 1.7.0.2 is now three years old. Four patches per year is not *that* much, and not all of these are security patches.

### Update 07/2016

For the lazy, the current list is:

- SUPEE-1533: SUPEE-1533 - Magento-CE-v1.7.x (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-1868: Magento-CE-v1.7.x (0.01 MB)
- APPSEC-212: Magento-CE-v1.6.0.0-1.7.0.2 (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-2725: Magento-CE-v1.7.0.0-1.8.1.0 (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-4291/4334: Magento-CE-v1.7.x-1.8.x (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-5344: SUPEE-5344 - Magento-CE-v1.7.x (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-5994: SUPEE-5994 for CE 1.6.0.0 - 1.9.1.1 (0.04 MB)
- SUPEE-6237: USPS API Patch - SUPEE-6237 - CE 1.6.x-1.9.1.x (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-6285: SUPEE-6285 for CE 1.7.0.0 - 1.7.0.2 (0.05 MB)
- SUPEE-6482: SUPEE-6482 for CE 1.7.x - 1.8.0.0 (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-6788: SUPEE-6788 for CE 1.7.0.2 (0.17 MB)
- SUPEE-7405: SUPEE-7405 for CE 1.7.0.0-1.7.0.2 (0.11 MB)
- SUPEE-7405 v1.1: SUPEE-7405 v1.1 for CE 1.7.0.2 (0.01 MB)
- SUPEE-7616: SUPEE-7616 for CE 1.4.2.0 - 1.7.0.2 (0.01 MB)
- PHP 5.4: Magento-CE-v1.7.0.0-1.7.0.2 (0.01 MB)

If http://fabrizioballiano.net/magento-patches/ is not available, you can always check if there are new patches at https://www.magentocommerce.com/download > Release Archives > Magento Community Edition Patches - 1.x  **(new patches are added at the top)**

---

**Also, you should subscribe to the official security newsletter at https://magento.com/security to be informed about new patches in time.**

Comment: I kind of was thinking, that there was a new 1.7 point release - but there wasn't. Must have confused that with 1.9